# Ordinal interpretation of Friedman's $n$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, order-theory, ordinals, trees

I heard that Kruskal's tree theorem can be turned into a finite form that creates an extremely fast growing function because ordinals could be encoded into trees.

On this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem#ref_n_k.5E_.2A) it mentions that there is another very fast growing function (but it's not quite as fast) called $n$.

> $n(k)$ is defined as the length of the longest possible sequence that can be constructed with a k-letter alphabet such that no block of letters $x_i$,...,$x_{2i}$ is a subsequence of any later block

I think that is related to [Higman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma)

so I was wondering what is the interpretation of this in terms of ordinals? I guess it must be related to an ordinal between $\epsilon_0$ and $\Gamma_0$.

---

How can I explain it better. The Ackermann and Goodstein function is fast growing and the TREE function is fast growing, because they are produced from ordinal notations (for up to omega^2 (or is it omega^omega of Primitive recursive arithmetic?), epsilon_0 and Gamma_0 respectively) that measure the proof strength of some theories.. so they are faster than any total function in those theories. I want to know what ordinal and theory is $n$ associated with.

If you understand my meaning please feel free to edit my question. I am only starting at logic so I don't know how to state it formally.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "interpretation of $n$ in terms of ordinals"?

Comment: @ArthurFischer, I've tried

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is indeed an ordinal interpretation of Friedman's block subsequence theorem;  however, the associated ordinal is not between $\varepsilon_0$ and $\Gamma_0$;  it is $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$.  More precisely, k-labelled sequences have ordinal $\omega^{\omega^{k-1}}$.  Friedman's block subsequence theorem is provable in the theory $I\Sigma_3$ but not the theory $I\Sigma_2$; the latter has poof theoretic ordinal $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$.

The ordering on sequences of order type $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ is as follows:

1-labelled sequences are determined by their length, i.e. 1 < 11 < 111 ... .

Assume now that have ordered k-labelled sequences; we will now order k+1-labelled sequences.  Let S and T be two k+1-labelled sequences.  If one of S or T has more appearances of k+1 than the other, that sequence will be considered greater.  Otherwise,  suppose both S and T have n appearances of k+1;  express S and T as

$S = S_0$ k+1 $S_1$ k+1 ... k+1 $S_n$

$T = T_0$ k+1 $T_1$ k+1 ... k+1 $T_n$

where the $S_i$ and $T_i$ are k-labelled sequences.  Compare the $S_i$ and the $T_i$ lexicographically, i.e. first compare $S_0$ to $T_0$, then $S_1$ to $T_1$, etc.  For the smallest $i$ for which $S_i$ and $T_i$ differ, if $S_i > T_i$, then $S > T$;  if $S_i < T_i$, then $S < T$.  This defines the ordering.

Now I will demostrate that k-labelled sequences have order type $\omega^{\omega^{k-1}}$.  Clearly, 1-labelled sequences have order type $\omega = \omega^{\omega^{1-1}}$.  Suppose that we have proven that k-labelled sequences have order type $\omega^{\omega^{k-1}}$.  Let S be a k+1 labelled sequence, and express S as

$S = S_0$ k+1 $S_1$ k+1 ... k+1 $S_n$.

where the $S_i$ represent k-labelled sequences. Let $\alpha_i$ be the ordinals representing $S_i$.  We have $\alpha_i < \omega^{\omega^{k-1}}$ for all $i$.  Then $S$ will be associated with the ordinal

$\omega^{\omega^{k-1}n} (1+\alpha_0) + \omega^{\omega^{k-1}(n-1)} \alpha_1 + \ldots + \omega^{\omega^{k-1}} \alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_n$.

I leave it to the reader to show that this association will yield the same ordering as our previously defined ordering.  This identifies k+1-labelled sequences with ordinals up to $\omega^{\omega^{k}}$, as desired.

Friedman's n(k) grows at a rate similar to that of $H_{\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}}(k)$ in the Hardy hierarchy, which is equal to $F_{\omega^{\omega}}(k)$ in the fast-growing hierarchy;  you lose an $\omega$ when converting to the fast-growing hierarchy.

Comment: Fantastic.   Can you read off from this the ordinal such that proving it well-ordered is equivalent to proving that the function n(k) is total?

Comment: I think so.  I believe that one can show that 'PRA proves "f(n) is total" if and only if "omega^omega^omega is well-ordered" ' is equivalent to 'f(n) is omega^omega^omega-recursive, but is not a-recursive for any a < omega^omega^omega. The latter statement is the subject of section 5 of Friedman's "Long Finite Sequences." Certainly if you have transfinite induction up to omega^omega^omega, one can construct any omega^omega^omega-recursive function, so you can prove that f(n) is total.  But I am not sure of the other direction.

Answer (score 4):

According to the end of section 5 of Friedman's paper

http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/finiteseq10_8_98.pdf

$n(k)$  is situated at level $\omega^\omega$ of the extension of the hierarchy of primitive recursive functions past $\omega$.  In computational terms he cites earlier papers showing that this level of the hierarchy contains (and is exhausted by) something called "nested multiple recursive functions".  Based on this I would guess that the answer is along the following lines, and is far below $\epsilon_0$:

- proving that $n(k)$ is finite for all $k$ is equivalent (over PRA) to proving ${\omega^\omega}$ is well ordered (or the same idea with a stack of $3$ or $4$ $\omega$'s)
- there is a natural subsystem of PA (extending PRA) that can prove, for any nested multiple recursive function, that the function is total
- the proof theoretic ordinal of this system is $\omega^{\omega^{\dots \omega}}$, where the exponential tower has between $2$ and $4$ $\omega$'s
- there is a restriction of the $\epsilon_0$ ordinal notation, such as limiting the depth or width of some of the trees to a small value (such as $3$ or $4$ or $5$) that gives a natural graphic notation for the ordinals up to the one you want.

Comment: Theorem 5.19 in that paper shows $n()$ to be at level $\omega^{\omega}$ in the fast-growing hierarchy -- far below  $\epsilon_0$, as you guessed.

Comment: @r.e.s., thanks.  The level in the fast-growing hierarchy does not map exactly to proof theoretic ordinal but I think it should be an exponential tower of similar height.